# How do I setup a map for a unique identifier?

Tags: java

We have an database table and the unique index on that table is a composite key (String, int, int). I want to add a field in my Java class that will hold this key. I tried:

```
Map<String, Integer, Integer>
```

but the IDE told me I cannot do that as a map is just Map K,V.

My question is what is the best way to represent this key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Map<String, Integer, Integer>
```

That does not work, because `Map` takes only two type parameters (for the key and the value), not three.

Create a class that represents the key. Use that as a key in the map. Note: The key class must implement the `hashCode` and `equals` methods correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just create a custom key like this -

```
class MyKey{
   int key1;
   int key2;
   String key3;
   // override hashCode & equals
}
```

You can then use this class as your key

```
Map<MyKey, Value>
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to do with it:

You can create a bean as key:

```
public class MyCompositeKey {
    private String field1;
    private Integer field2, field3;

    //getters and setters here


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
    //your implementation here, you can use here the hashCode of Integer and String
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof MyCompositeKey) {
            MyCompositeKey that=(MyCompositeKey) o;
            //compare here the fields  
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or you can do something like:

```
String key=field1+"-"+field2+"-"+field3;
```

and use that String as key in your map.

Or maybe you just need a `List<Comparable>` where you add the three elements in a prefixed order.